# Ubicar y hacer que el elemento con "position: absolute" no se quede estático con el scroll

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

tengo un pequeño problema con mi proyecto que es un editor de código HTML, donde la capa del código donde se dibujaban los colores del código se quedaba en el mismo lugar al hacer scroll, así que hice un ejemplo del error para que no tengan que leer código que no tiene nada que ver con el comportamiento.

En resumen, tengo un div padre con `overflow-y: scroll` entonces los elementos hijos se deberían mover al hacer scroll, pero esto no me está funcionando con el elemento hijo con `position: absolute`

Codigo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: rgb(30,30,30);
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.code_content {
  position: unset !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: none;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dummy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.code {
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="code_content">
  <div class="dummy">
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
  </div>
  <div class="code">
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo doy por resuelto si logran que al hacer scroll en el `div.code_content` se mueva el `div.dummy` y `div.code` (por lo que parecería que solo hay 1 texto)

Muchas gracias por adelantado :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo elimina la línea `position: unset !important;` y coloca un `position: relative;` en el `.code_content`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: rgb(30,30,30);
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.code_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: none;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.dummy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.code {
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="code_content">
  <div class="dummy">
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
  </div>
   <div class="code">
    AA
    AA
    AA
    AA
    <strong>AA</strong>
  </div>
 
</div>
```